# Visual Studio Code Javascript Intellisense not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

When I use vscode and go to a script.js file intellisense will not work but intellisense works on everything else, variables, function and more will not show up. Thanks.

Comment: Restart or open another simple js file to see if the issue still existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often have that happen and a restart of VS Code or closing the file and reopening it resolves it.

You could also reinstall the intellicode extension and see if that is a more permanent resolution.